how to deploy artemis-ra-rar to weblogic 12c
I am trying to deploy artemis-ra-rar from the Apache Artemis examples version 2.19.1
I am limited to this version because of the version of Java.
My knowledge of Weblogic is not very good but I was successful at deploying a version of the resource adapter where I could see the different objects created in the JNDI tree.
However, when I try to use the resources, I run in 2 distinct problems.
Here are the files from the currently deployed resource adapter:
ra.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connector xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/connector_1_5.xsd"
           version="1.5">

    <description>ActiveMQ Artemis Resource Adapter</description>
    <display-name>ArtemisRA</display-name>
    <vendor-name>Apache Software Foundation</vendor-name>
    <eis-type>JMS 2.0 Server</eis-type>
    <resourceadapter-version>1.0</resourceadapter-version>

    <license>
        <description>
            Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
            contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
            this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
            The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
            (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
            the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

            http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

            Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
            distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
            WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
            See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
            limitations under the License.
        </description>
        <license-required>true</license-required>
    </license>

    <resourceadapter>
        <resourceadapter-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter</resourceadapter-class>
        <config-property>
            <description>
                The transport type. Multiple connectors can be configured by using a comma separated list,
                i.e.
                org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory,org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.invm.InVMConnectorFactory.
            </description>
            <config-property-name>ConnectorClassName</config-property-name>
            <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
            <config-property-value>org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
            </config-property-value>
        </config-property>
        <config-property>
            <description>The transport configuration. These values must be in the form of key=val;key=val;,
                if multiple connectors are used then each set must be separated by a comma i.e.
                host=host1;port=61616,host=host2;port=61617.
                Each set of params maps to the connector classname specified.
            </description>
            <config-property-name>ConnectionParameters</config-property-name>
            <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
            <config-property-value>host=myhost1.dev;port=61616</config-property-value>
        </config-property>

        <config-property>
            <config-property-name>HA</config-property-name>
            <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
            <config-property-value>true</config-property-value>
        </config-property>

        <config-property>
            <config-property-name>UserName</config-property-name>
            <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
            <config-property-value>tanycast</config-property-value>
        </config-property>

        <config-property>
            <config-property-name>Password</config-property-name>
            <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
            <config-property-value>(tanycast)</config-property-value>
        </config-property>

        <outbound-resourceadapter>
            <connection-definition>
                <managedconnectionfactory-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAManagedConnectionFactory
                </managedconnectionfactory-class>

                <config-property>
                    <description>The default session type</description>
                    <config-property-name>SessionDefaultType</config-property-name>
                    <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
                    <config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</config-property-value>
                </config-property>
                <config-property>
                    <description>Whether or not to participate in a JTA transaction, this is used if the RA does not
                        have access to the Transaction Manager
                    </description>
                    <config-property-name>InJtaTransaction</config-property-name>
                    <config-property-type>java.lang.Boolean</config-property-type>
                    <config-property-value>true</config-property-value>
                </config-property>
                <config-property>
                    <description>Try to obtain a lock within specified number of seconds; less than or equal to 0
                        disable this functionality
                    </description>
                    <config-property-name>UseTryLock</config-property-name>
                    <config-property-type>java.lang.Integer</config-property-type>
                    <config-property-value>0</config-property-value>
                </config-property>

                <connectionfactory-interface>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAConnectionFactory
                </connectionfactory-interface>
                <connectionfactory-impl-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAConnectionFactoryImpl
                </connectionfactory-impl-class>
                <connection-interface>javax.jms.Session</connection-interface>
                <connection-impl-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASession</connection-impl-class>
            </connection-definition>
            <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
            <authentication-mechanism>
                <authentication-mechanism-type>BasicPassword</authentication-mechanism-type>
                <credential-interface>javax.resource.spi.security.PasswordCredential</credential-interface>
            </authentication-mechanism>
            <reauthentication-support>false</reauthentication-support>
        </outbound-resourceadapter>

        <inbound-resourceadapter>
            <messageadapter>
                <messagelistener>
                    <messagelistener-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messagelistener-type>
                    <activationspec>
                        <activationspec-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec
                        </activationspec-class>
                        <required-config-property>
                            <config-property-name>destination</config-property-name>
                        </required-config-property>
                    </activationspec>
                </messagelistener>
            </messageadapter>
        </inbound-resourceadapter>

        <adminobject>
            <adminobject-interface>javax.jms.Queue</adminobject-interface>
            <adminobject-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue</adminobject-class>
            <config-property>
                <config-property-name>Address</config-property-name>
                <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
                <config-property-value>artemis.ra.test.anycast</config-property-value>
            </config-property>
        </adminobject>

        <adminobject>
            <adminobject-interface>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</adminobject-interface>
            <adminobject-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory</adminobject-class>
            <config-property>
                <config-property-name>BrokerURL</config-property-name>
                <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
            </config-property>
        </adminobject>
        <adminobject>
            <adminobject-interface>javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory</adminobject-interface>
            <adminobject-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory</adminobject-class>
            <config-property>
                <config-property-name>BrokerURL</config-property-name>
                <config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
            </config-property>
        </adminobject>
    </resourceadapter>
</connector>

weblogic-ra.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-connector xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-connector"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-connector http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-connector/1.5/weblogic-connector.xsd">
    <!-- Outbound Resource Adapter -->
    <admin-objects>
        <admin-object-group>
            <admin-object-interface>javax.jms.Queue</admin-object-interface>
            <admin-object-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQQueue</admin-object-class>
            <admin-object-instance>
                <jndi-name>jms/queue/ArtemisTestAnycast</jndi-name>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>Address</name>
                        <value>artemis.ra.test.anycast</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </admin-object-instance>
        </admin-object-group>
        <admin-object-group>
            <admin-object-interface>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</admin-object-interface>
            <admin-object-class>org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory</admin-object-class>
            <admin-object-instance>
                <jndi-name>jms/DirectConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>BrokerURL</name>
                        <value>(tcp://myhost1.dev:61616)?ha=true</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>UserName</name>
                        <value>tanycast</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>Password</name> 
                        <value>(tanycast)</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </admin-object-instance>
        </admin-object-group>
    </admin-objects>
    <outbound-resource-adapter>
        <connection-definition-group>
            <connection-factory-interface>org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAConnectionFactory</connection-factory-interface>
            <connection-instance>
                <jndi-name>jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
                <connection-properties>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>BrokerURL</name>
                            <value>(tcp://myhost1.dev:61616)?ha=true</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>UserName</name>
                            <value>tanycast</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>Password</name>
                            <value>(tanycast)</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </connection-properties>
            </connection-instance>
        </connection-definition-group>
    </outbound-resource-adapter>
</weblogic-connector>

I have tried 2 different approaches.

I tried to use the jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory, that instanciates a org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAConnectionFactory

with my basic web-app calling it in a Servlet
package com.example.jms;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet("/send")
public class JmsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name = "jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory", lookup = "jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(name = "jms/queue/ArtemisTestAnycast")
    private Queue queue;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        log("connectionFactory: " + connectionFactory);
        String messageText = req.getParameter("message");
        try (Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
             Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {

            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(messageText);
            producer.send(message);

            resp.getWriter().write("Message sent: " + messageText);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Failed to send message", e);
        }
    }
}

The resource adapter deploys and starts fine, but when I call my method, I get the following exception:
<Dec 13, 2024 6:40:41,745 PM GMT> <Info> <Common> <BEA-000640> <Resource Pool "jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory" resuming by external command (multi data source or console or other).>
<Dec 13, 2024 6:40:41,746 PM GMT> <Info> <ServletContext-/JMSDemoApp> <BEA-000000> <com.example.jms.JmsServlet: connectionFactory: weblogic.deployment.jms.PooledConnectionFactory@1d5f4768>
<Dec 13, 2024 6:40:41,751 PM GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@33646340[app:JMSDemoApp module:JMSDemoApp.war path:null spec-version:3.1]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: This method is not applicable inside the application server. See the J2EE spec, e.g. J2EE1.4 Section 6.6
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.setExceptionListener(ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.java:588)
        at weblogic.deployment.jms.JMSSessionPool.getConnectionHelper(JMSSessionPool.java:617)
        at weblogic.deployment.jms.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(PooledConnectionFactory.java:426)
        at weblogic.deployment.jms.PooledConnectionFactory.createConnection(PooledConnectionFactory.java:271)
        at com.example.jms.JmsServlet.doPost(JmsServlet.java:25)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

>
<Dec 13, 2024 6:40:41,752 PM GMT> <Warning> <JMSPool> <BEA-169807> <There was an error while making the initial connection to the JMS resource named jms/ActiveMQConnectionFactory from within an EJB or a servlet. The server will attempt the connection again later. The error was javax.jms.IllegalStateException: This method is not applicable inside the application server. See the J2EE spec, e.g. J2EE1.4 Section 6.6>

My understanding is that org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQRAConnectionFactory is wrapped in a PooledConnectionFactory specific to Weblogic and fails when the method setExceptionListener(ActiveMQRASessionFactoryImpl.java:588) is called.

I have tried to use DirectConnectionFactory that instanciates a org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory in a hope to bypass the PooledConnection created by the server.

With this approach, I end up a little further, the connection to the server seems to work, because the server rejects a user that is null despite the fact that I have set the properties.
If I deploy my test web-app with the following configuration:
@WebServlet("/send")
public class JmsServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Resource(name = "jms/DirectConnectionFactory", lookup = "jms/DirectConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;


I get the following exception:
<Dec 13, 2024 6:59:04,366 PM GMT> <Info> <Common> <BEA-000640> <Resource Pool "jms/DirectConnectionFactory" resuming by external command (multi data source or console or other).>
<Dec 13, 2024 6:59:04,626 PM GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@1888612433[app:JMSDemoApp module:JMSDemoApp.war path:null spec-version:3.1]] Root cause of ServletException.
javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from 10.232.194.90:55502. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:549)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:443)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:306)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:254)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionChannel(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1437)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:743)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection.authorize(ActiveMQConnection.java:661)
>
<Dec 13, 2024 6:59:04,863 PM GMT> <Warning> <JMSPool> <BEA-169807> <There was an error while making the initial connection to the JMS resource named jms/DirectConnectionFactory from within an EJB or a servlet. The server will attempt the connection again later. The error was javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from 10.232.194.90:55520. Username: null; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable>

My understanding is that the web-app is able to connect to the host, but the credentials are not correct (i.E: Unable to validate user from 10.232.194.90:55502. Username: null;)
I would be grateful if someone could:

validate my assumptions for case 1 and 2
direct me towards the correct approach
spot any mistakes that I have made.


The Java EE specification doesn't allow calling setExceptionListener from the servlet container. The exception message specifically says this:
This method is not applicable inside the application server. See the J2EE spec, e.g. J2EE1.4 Section 6.6

Section 6.6 of the J2EE1.4 spec says:

The following methods may only be used by application components
executing in the application client container:

javax.jms.Session method setMessageListener
javax.jms.Session method getMessageListener
javax.jms.Session method run
javax.jms.QueueConnection method createConnectionConsumer
javax.jms.TopicConnection method createConnectionConsumer
javax.jms.TopicConnection method createDurableConnectionConsumer
javax.jms.MessageConsumer method getMessageListener
javax.jms.MessageConsumer method setMessageListener
javax.jms.Connection method setExceptionListener
javax.jms.Connection method stop
javax.jms.Connection method setClientID


Therefore, you need to change your code so that it doesn't invoke setExceptionListener and instead deals with exceptions directly (i.e. without the listener).

thank you for your answer, I understand that I cannot use setExceptionListener(), but I am not calling it explicitly, I believe it is called when Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection() is called and cast automatically to a PooledConnection by Weblogic

Then that's either a bug in WebLogic or a a problem with your WebLogic configuration.
